# How to insert page number in Beamer navigation symbols?

Tags: beamer, header-footer, page-numbering

I created a presentation with Beamer, and I used Darmstadt theme.

But, this theme doesn't have the page number.

I know that I can insert the page number in Footline with:

```
\setbeamertemplate{footline}[frame number]
```

But, how can I insert the page number in *"Navigation symbols"*, like this picture?

[image]

Answer (score 148, accepted):

You can use something like

```
\addtobeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}{%
    \usebeamerfont{footline}%
    \usebeamercolor[fg]{footline}%
    \hspace{1em}%
    \insertframenumber/\inserttotalframenumber
}
```

and use spaces, font and boxes to adjust the alignment of the numbers with the navigation symbols.

You can change the font/color just by altering the font/color for `footline` as in

```
\setbeamercolor{footline}{fg=blue}
\setbeamerfont{footline}{series=\bfseries}
```

Comment: Ok. But, this disable all icons in navigation bar. I modified your code to:
`\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{%
 \insertslidenavigationsymbol
 \insertframenavigationsymbol
 \insertsubsectionnavigationsymbol
 \insertsectionnavigationsymbol
 \insertdocnavigationsymbol
 \insertbackfindforwardnavigationsymbol
 \hspace{1em}%
 \usebeamerfont{footline}
 \insertframenumber/\inserttotalframenumber%
}`

Comment: I will see how to modify text color to black.

Comment: @Anderson see the updated code: if you use `\addtobeamertemplate` instead of `\setbeamertemplate` you keep the symbols

Comment: I also just edited to suggest how to customise color and font (in a beamer idiomatic way)

Comment: To fix the vertical alignment of the page number, I used: `\raisebox{1.2pt}[0pt][0pt]{\insertframenumber/\inserttotalframenumber}`.

Comment: How do you avoid getting the frame numbers on the title page?

Answer (score 24):

You can add the following code before `\begin{document}`:

```
\expandafter\def\expandafter\insertshorttitle\expandafter{%
  \insertshorttitle\hfill%
  \insertframenumber\,/\,\inserttotalframenumber}
```

Comment: So happy I found this comment. This does exactly what I needed, independent of the theme I use. My macro vocab however is small, and I'm stuck trying to merge it with [another answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/183357/91319). My goal is to remove hyperref's linkcolor on \insertshorttitle in the footline in general, using something like `\let\hyperlink\@secondoftwo`. Is this an easy fix?

Comment: Consider my comment above [solved](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/214084/91319)!

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it worked! May I also ask you how can I flush it all the way right of the line? Thanks!

Answer (score 12):

Before `\begin{document}` you need to include:

```
\setbeamertemplate{sidebar right}{}
\setbeamertemplate{footline}{%
\hfill\usebeamertemplate***{navigation symbols}
\hspace{1cm}\insertframenumber{}/\inserttotalframenumber}
```

This should work to put the frame number beside the navigation bar, not sure how to put it inside of the navigation bar.

Comment: Ok. This works fine. But, I use "\logo" and "\setbeamertemplate{sidebar right}{}" disable the logo.

Comment: so if you add something like `\logo{\includegraphics[scale=0.2]{imageName.jpg} }` after the above code then you get no logo?

Comment: Yes. My tex file has a `\logo{\includegraphics[scale=.4]{logo-ic}}` after your code, but don't show the logo.

Answer (score 8):

Actually, I want to supplenment MaxGraves's answer! (but I don't have enough reputation, sorry about that!)

My result will put the "page/total page" rightside and inside the navigation bar, instead of outside.

Note: `\addtobeamertemplate{⟨element name⟩}{⟨pre-text⟩}{⟨post-text⟩}`, hence you have to notice which bracket you put "page/total page" in. In my case, using Frankfurt theme, which have default navigation bar, put the followings before `\begin{document}` will show my results as the bottom.

```
\addtobeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}{ \hspace{1em}    \usebeamerfont{footline}%
    \insertframenumber / \inserttotalframenumber }
```

The reason I use `\hspace{1em} \usebeamerfont{footline}` is for good-looking, the front makes "page/total page" not too close to navigation bar, and the latter is just make it as big as I hope, more clearly, I think....

[image: the result]

Comment: This looks like a *subset* of the accept one. Would like to explain more? For example why you keep `\usebeamerfont` but not `\usebeamercolor`. And why are there so many useless spaces?

Answer (score 1):

```
 \setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}
{  \insertslidenavigationsymbol 
insertframenavigationsymbol   
\insertsubsectionnavigationsymbol  
  \insertsectionnavigationsymbol
  \insertdocnavigationsymbol  
  \insertbackfindforwardnavigationsymbol 
 \hspace{1em}  
\usebeamerfont{footline} 
   \insertframenumber/\inserttotalframenumber }
 \setcounter{page}{1} 
\pagenumbering{arabic} 
%add this code before begin doc 
\begin{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to [tex.se]!  This seems to be a duplicate (with a missing `\\` typo) of code in Anderson's comment to Bordaigorl's answer.  That comment resulted in an a cleaner updated answer.  In any case, code only answers are best combined with some text explanation.

Answer (score 1):

```
\setbeamertemplate{page number in head/foot}[totalframenumber]
\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty

\setbeamerfont{page number in head/foot}{size=\footnotesize}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Could you please extend your code snippet to a compilable and complete code?

Comment: Because the `Darmstadt` theme does not show any footline by default, you'll also have to set the `footline` template to make this work.