# How to remove link from title in foot

Tags: beamer, header-footer, links

When using `\insertshorttitle` in the footline (or elsewhere) it is automatically inserted as a click-able link.

Therefore it is for example typesetted in a different colour. (marked with a red circle in the image, where the title appears black instead of blue)

How can this behaviour be disabled?

> [image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\setbeamertemplate{footline}{
    \leavevmode%
    \hbox{%
        \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.333333\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{author in head/foot}%
            \usebeamerfont{author in head/foot}\insertshortauthor
        \end{beamercolorbox}%
        \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.333333\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{title in head/foot}%
            \usebeamerfont{title in head/foot}\insertshorttitle
        \end{beamercolorbox}%
    }%
    \vskip0pt%
}

\title{test}
\author{Einstein}

\begin{document}

    \begin{frame}
        test
    \end{frame}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The link is *not* the culprit that the color for the title is different than the color for the author in the footer.

`themes/outer/beamerouterthememiniframes.sty` defines:

```
\setbeamercolor{section in head/foot}{parent=palette tertiary}
\setbeamercolor{subsection in head/foot}{parent=palette secondary}
\setbeamercolor{author in head/foot}{parent=subsection in head/foot}
\setbeamercolor{title in head/foot}{parent=section in head/foot}
```

The different color is a property of `title in head/foot` and can be changed, e.g.:

```
\setbeamercolor{title in head/foot}{parent=subsection in head/foot}
```

Color of links can be disabled by

```
\hypersetup{allcolors={}}
```

or more complete:

```
\hypersetup{hidelinks}
```

This also removes link borders.

Full example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\hypersetup{
  colorlinks,
  linkcolor=red,
}

\setbeamercolor{title in head/foot}{parent=subsection in head/foot}
\setbeamertemplate{footline}{%
  \leavevmode
  \hbox{%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[
      wd=.333333\paperwidth,
      ht=2.25ex,
      dp=1ex,
      center
    ]{author in head/foot}%
      \usebeamerfont{author in head/foot}%
      \insertshortauthor
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[
      wd=.333333\paperwidth,
      ht=2.25ex,
      dp=1ex,
      center
    ]{title in head/foot}%
      \usebeamerfont{title in head/foot}%
      % disable color in links
      % \hypersetup{allcolors={}}%
      \hypersetup{hidelinks}%
      \insertshorttitle
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
  }%
  \par
  \vspace{0pt}%
}

\title{test}
\author{Einstein}

\begin{document}

  \begin{frame}
    test
    \begin{equation}
      \label{eq:einstein}  
      E=mc^2
    \end{equation}

    \vspace{0pt plus 5fill}
    A reference to an \hyperref[eq:einstein]{equation}
    to show the link color.
  \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: Thanks for having a look into it! Unfortunatly this seems not to work, if I mess around with the link color, e.g. `\hypersetup{colorlinks=true, linkcolor=red}`. But in combination with @Werners anwser it gives the desired result. A shame one could not accept multiple answers!!

Comment: @samcarter: The link decorations can be easily removed: `\hypersetup{hidelinks}`, see updated answer.

Answer (score 9):

You can turn off the [`hyperref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref) functionality momentarily in the footer:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\let\Tiny=\tiny% https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/58087/5764

\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{footline}{
  \leavevmode%
  \hbox{%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.333333\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{author in head/foot}%
      \usebeamerfont{author in head/foot}\insertshortauthor
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.333333\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{title in head/foot}%
      \usebeamerfont{title in head/foot}\let\hyperlink\@secondoftwo\insertshorttitle
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
  }%
  \vskip0pt%
}
\makeatother
\title{test}
\author{Einstein}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  test
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

`\insertshorttitle` inserts a `\hyperlink{<target>}{<title>}`, where `<title>` is the formatted title as it appears in the presentation. I've inserted `\let\hyperlink\@secondoftwo` just before `\insertshorttitle` which makes `\hyperlink` just return the second argument - skipping the entire hyperlinking. Since this is performed inside a group (offered by the `\begin`...`\end` of `beamercolorbox`), the redefinition or `\let`tting is temporary/limited in scope.

The additional [`\makeatletter`...`\makeatother` pair](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/8351/5764) is required since `\@secondoftwo` uses `@` in the macro definition.

Answer (score 0):

In themes with footers split in three parts, like Boadilla, you can use the following, instead of the other answers:

```
\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{footline}{
  \leavevmode%
  \hbox{%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.333333\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{author in head/foot}%
      \usebeamerfont{author in head/foot}\insertshortauthor
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.333333\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{title in head/foot}%
      \usebeamerfont{title in head/foot}\let\hyperlink\@secondoftwo\insertshorttitle
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.333333\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{date in head/foot}%
      \usebeamerfont{date in head/foot}\let\hyperlink\@secondoftwo\insertshortdate
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
  }%
  \vskip0pt%
}
\makeatother
\expandafter\def\expandafter\insertshortdate\expandafter{%
  \insertshortdate\hfill%
  \insertframenumber\,/\,\inserttotalframenumber}
```

This will keep the section title and the counter of slides.