# Beamer: hyperlinks and short title colors

Tags: beamer, hyperref

Consider the following MWE

```
\documentclass[leqno]{beamer}

\usetheme{Madrid}
\usecolortheme{whale}

\usepackage{lmodern}
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true, allcolors=blue}

\title[Short title]{Title}
\author{John Doe}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \begin{equation}
  \label{eq:foo}
      2 + 2 = 4
  \end{equation}

  Hyperlink: \ref{eq:foo}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

I want my short title foreground color to be white and my hyperlinks blue. However setting  `colorlinks=true, allcolors=blue` also sets a blue color for the short title. I tried setting `\setbeamercolor{title in head/foot}{fg=white}` but it doesn't seem to have any effect.

[image]

I found this [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/183357/9953) that apparently addresses the same/similar problem. In order to just change the color of the short title is it also necessary (an the only workaround available) to temporarily disable hyperref functionality in the footer?

Comment: you can force a white color using `\title[\color{white}Short title]{Title}` (or `\textcolor{}{}`) It's not very elegant but shouldn't have any side effect

Comment: @dcmst thanks for your answer. I was in fact doing exactly that until now but also find that solution a bit dirty. If there isn't a more general yet simple solution then I'll stick to your workaround.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can change `allcolors` to the current color `.` inside the `footline` template using

```
\addtobeamertemplate{footline}{\hypersetup{allcolors=.}}{}
```

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass[leqno]{beamer}

\usetheme{Madrid}
\usecolortheme{whale}

\usepackage{lmodern}
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true, allcolors=blue}
\addtobeamertemplate{footline}{\hypersetup{allcolors=.}}{}

\title[Short title]{Title}
\author{John Doe}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \begin{equation}
  \label{eq:foo}
      2 + 2 = 4
  \end{equation}

  Hyperlink: \ref{eq:foo}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is much more elegant that the other answer :-)

Comment: Lovely answer, solved [my question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/137022/how-to-insert-page-number-in-beamer-navigation-bars/218180#comment1071980_218180) too.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure if there is some reason not to do this but very hasty testing suggests that hyperlinks work and the short title appears in white:

```
\documentclass[leqno]{beamer}

\usetheme{Madrid}
\usecolortheme{whale}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\insertshorttitle[1][]{%
  \beamer@setupshort{#1}%
  \let\thanks=\@gobble%
  \ifnum\c@page=1%
  \hyperlinkpresentationend{\beamer@insertshort{\usebeamercolor*[fg]{title in head/foot}\beamer@shorttitle}}%
  \else%
  \hyperlinkpresentationstart{\beamer@insertshort{\usebeamercolor*[fg]{title in head/foot}\beamer@shorttitle}}%
  \fi}
\makeatother

\usepackage{lmodern}
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true, allcolors=blue}

\title[Short title]{Title}
\author{John Doe}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}
  \begin{frame}
    \titlepage
  \end{frame}

\begin{frame}
  \begin{equation}
  \label{eq:foo}
      2 + 2 = 4
  \end{equation}

  Hyperlink: \ref{eq:foo}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[I added the title page just to check the hyperlinking actually did something.]

[image: hyperlinked short title in white?]

**Updated** to use samcarter's suggestion which enhances flexibility.

Comment: Perhaps one could replace the `\color{white}` by `\usebeamercolor*[fg]{title in head/foot}` to make it more flexible

Comment: @samcarter You are quite right - thanks! I've updated the code.

Comment: Can this be achieved by patching the `\insertshorttitle` command with the `etoolbox` package? I tried `\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\insertshorttitle}{\beamer@shorttitle}{\usebeamercolor*[fg]{title
  in head/foot}\beamer@shorttitle}{}{}
\makeatother` but it didn't work.

Comment: @petobens I'm not sure why that wouldn't work. But `beamer`'s code always seems complex and I always find it difficult to even trace what is doing what, even before trying to change it in some way. Why do you wish to do it that way particularly? That is, does renewing the command as I did cause side-effects?

Comment: @crf your solution works great. I was just wondering if it could be make a bit more compact by using etoolbox and just patching the `\insertshorttitle` command. Can you try patching it? Thanks!

Comment: @petobens OK. I've looked into this. `etoolbox` reports the command as patchable but if any search text is specified, it reports it as unpatchable. (You can use `\tracingpatches` in the preamble and `\ifpatchable...`, `\ifpatchable*...` to test this.) `etoolbox` suggests 3 possible reasons. Two of these are irrelevant since the problem occurs without specifying replacement text. So my guess is the remaining one: `the macro may have been defined under a category code regime different from the current one`. I know very little about cat codes. However, `beamerbasedecode.sty` may be interesting...

Comment: Personally, though, I do not think it is worth pursuing this if the only motivation is marginally more concise code. First, it will be a lot of work to save a little code. Second, you will need to adjust the category codes before patching the command, I think, and then readjust them after patching. I doubt that the result will be more compact than the code in my answer.

Comment: @petobens Maybe there is something in that file you could use to switch the cat codes back and forth. However, I don't understand it well enough to make use of it. You may be more insightful ;).

Comment: @cfr Thanks for looking into this! And for explaining why this might not work. I know almost nothing about cat codes so I can't provide any insight. Therefore I will stick to your code which works just fine. Thanks once again.

Comment: @cfr I've posted a follow-up question [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/204701/9953). Thanks once again for looking into this.