# Madrid head/foot text color

Tags: beamer

I am working with the madrid theme for my presentation but the text of section in the headline and  title in the footline appears in red, I am trying to change it. How can'i proceed. Sorry I used the following code

```
\documentclass[hyperref={pdfpagemode=FullScreen,colorlinks=true},xcolor={dvipsnames,svgnames,table}]{beamer}

 \usepackage{concrete} 

 \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

 \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

 \usepackage[frenchb]{babel}
\usetheme[secheader]{Madrid}



\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
 \author{Ikondo}
 \title[Variability]{\textsc{Variability}}

 \institute{My university}

 \usecolortheme{albatross}

 \begin{document}                         


 \begin{frame}[plain]%\thispagestyle{empty}

 \begin{columns}
 \begin{column}{9cm}
 \includegraphics[width=2.3cm, height=1.7cm]{logo1.jpg} %\hspace*{1.52cm}
 \end{column}
 \begin{column}{2cm}
 \includegraphics[width=2.1cm, height=1.7cm]{logo2.jpg} 
 \end{column}
 \end{columns}

 \begin{center}

 \begin{minipage}{100mm}

 \centering
 \begin{block}{}


 \begin{center}
 \textrm{Vriability}
 \end{center}
 \end{block}

 \end{minipage}

 \end{center}

 \begin{center}
 \includegraphics[width=2.5cm,height=1.5cm]{logo3.jpg} \\

 institute \\
 \vspace{0.2cm}
 Report \\
 %\end{center}
 \begin{columns}
 \begin{column}{3cm}
 \includegraphics[width=2.1cm, height=1cm]{logo4.jpg} %\hspace*{1.52cm}
 \end{column}
 \begin{column}{2cm}
 \includegraphics[width=2.1cm, height=1cm]{logo5.png} 
 \end{column}
 \end{columns}
 \end{center}
 \end{frame}

 %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


 \section{Methodes}
   \subsection{structure}
  \begin{frame}


  \begin{block}{bantou}
   Le texte de ma diapo.
   \end{block}
  \end{frame}
   \end{document}
  \section{Données}
   \begin{frame}
 \transblindshorizontal
 %\transwipe
   \includegraphics[width=10cm,height=8cm]{fig1.jpg}\\
    \end{frame}


  \section{résultats}
  \subsection{structure} 
   \begin{frame}
 \transsplitverticalout
 %\transwipe
   \includegraphics[width=10cm,height=8cm]{fig2.jpg}\\
    \end{frame}
 \end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. Could you add a Minimal Working (or not) Example? Some code starting with `\documentclass` and finishing with `\end{document}` which we can copy and easily modify. It will be easy to help you.

Comment: Maybe [Beamer: hyperlinks and short title colors](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/214084/43317) or [Changing URL colors in headline / footline of beamer template](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/214090/43317) will help.

Answer (score 1):

You can use some predefined color theme, e.g.

```
\usetheme{Madrid}
\usecolortheme{default}
% default albatross beaver beetle crane dolphin dove
% fly lily orchid rose seagull seahorse whale wolverine
```

which will change the colors in your presentation easily.

See also http://www.hartwork.org/beamer-theme-matrix/.

EDIT: Based on the example you provided, the color is due to the `colorlinks=true` option. If you remove it, then the header/footer will be colored according to the theme used. You can also follow [this link](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/203071/62152) to add color to hyperlinks in the document but not in the header/footer.

Comment: I tried this options but they did not change the textcolor of the the title in the footline!!!!!

Comment: Then you have to post here your document, because this is clearly not a standard behaviour.

Comment: Sorry,  I used the following code