# Patch \insertshorttitle in beamer

Tags: beamer, etoolbox, catcodes, patching

In this [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/201740/9953) @cfr showed me how to preserve short title color in beamer while allowing hyperlinks to work. His solution was to modify the `\insertshorttitle` command (defined in `beamerbasetitle.sty`) like this:

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\insertshorttitle[1][]{%
  \beamer@setupshort{#1}%
  \let\thanks=\@gobble%
  \ifnum\c@page=1%
  \hyperlinkpresentationend{\beamer@insertshort{\usebeamercolor*[fg]{title in head/foot}\beamer@shorttitle}}%
  \else%
  \hyperlinkpresentationstart{\beamer@insertshort{\usebeamercolor*[fg]{title in head/foot}\beamer@shorttitle}}%
  \fi}
\makeatother
```

This works just fine but I want to know if it possible to just patch the `\insertshorttitle` command using `etoolbox`. I tried doing

```
\makeatletter 
\patchcmd{\insertshorttitle}{\beamer@shorttitle}{\usebeamercolor*[fg]{title in head/foot}\beamer@shorttitle}{}{} 
\makeatother
```

but it didn't work. `etoolbox` [suggested](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/201727/beamer-hyperlinks-and-short-title-colors/201740?noredirect=1#comment477971_201740) that the command is not patchable because "the macro may have been defined under a category code regime different from the current one".

So my question is: can I patch the command somehow? Here is a complete MWE:

```
\documentclass[leqno]{beamer}

\usetheme{Madrid}
\usecolortheme{whale}

\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true, allcolors=blue}

\makeatletter 
\patchcmd{\insertshorttitle}{\beamer@shorttitle}{\usebeamercolor*[fg]{title in head/foot}\beamer@shorttitle}{}{} 
\makeatother

\title[Short title]{Title}
\author{John Doe}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \begin{equation}
  \label{eq:foo}
      2 + 2 = 4
  \end{equation}

  Hyperlink: \ref{eq:foo}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\insertshorttitle` is defined with an optional argument, so `\patchcmd` doesn't work. Use `\xpatchcmd` of the `xpatch` package. See [Please tutor the usage of `\patchcmd` and `xpatch`](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/152773/)

Comment: For the record, that's a quote from `etoolbox`'s output. I said it suggested 3 possible reasons of which 2 did not apply, which only left that one. What I mean is, I did not pretend to *understand* that explanation ;)!

Comment: @cfr feel free to edit my question accordingly.

Comment: @egreg If I try this in a simple-minded way, it doesn't work. The command is patched but the subtitle only shows in the correct colour on the first of the two slides in [my MWE](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/201740/), whereas when I `\renewcommand` (as I did there), it works correctly even in the second frame. The hyperlink is created but the text does not show in the patched colour.

Comment: @cfr Two patches are needed, because `\patchcmd` (on which `\xpatchcmd` of `xpatch` is based) just patches the first occurrence.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When a patch is tried, it's very useful to add `\tracingpatches` and look at the relevant message in the log file (interactive compilation is better). In this case you'd get

```
[debug] tracing \patchcmd on input line 12
[debug] analyzing '\insertshorttitle'
[debug] ++ control sequence is defined
[debug] ++ control sequence is a macro
[debug] -- macro cannot be retokenized cleanly
[debug] -> the macro may have been defined under a category
[debug]    code regime different from the current one
[debug] -> the replacement text may contain special control
[debug]    sequence tokens formed with \csname...\endcsname;
[debug] -> the replacement text may contain carriage return,
[debug]    newline, or similar characters
```

which means that the patch didn't succeed. Often I also place `\ddt` (or any other undefined command) in the last argument, which is executed in case the patch fails, so the LaTeX run will be interrupted after that very message.

What happens is that `\insertshorttitle` has an optional argument, so it's not patchable with `\patchcmd` and this is one of the reasons I wrote the `xpatch` package.

If you say `\usepackage{xpatch}` and

```
\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd{\insertshorttitle}
  {\beamer@shorttitle}
  {\usebeamercolor*[fg]{title in head/foot}\beamer@shorttitle}
  {}{}
\makeatother
```

the debugging message will say

```
[debug] tracing \patchcmd on input line 12
[debug] analyzing '\\insertshorttitle'
[debug] ++ control sequence is defined
[debug] ++ control sequence is a macro
[debug] ++ macro can be retokenized cleanly
[debug] ++ search pattern found in replacement text
[debug] ++ patching possible
[debug] == retokenizing macro now
```

meaning success. However this patch is not sufficient, because it adds `\usebeamercolor*[fg]{title in head/foot}` only once. Indeed, adding `\xshowcmd\insertshortitle` after the patching command will reveal

```
> \\insertshorttitle=\long macro:
[#1]->\beamer@setupshort {#1}\let \thanks =\@gobble \ifnum \c@page =1\hyperlink
presentationend {\beamer@insertshort {\usebeamercolor *[fg]{title in head/foot}
\beamer@shorttitle }}\else \hyperlinkpresentationstart {\beamer@insertshort {\b
eamer@shorttitle }}\fi .
```

You must add a second patch, the complete set would be

```
\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd{\insertshorttitle}
  {\beamer@shorttitle}
  {\usebeamercolor*[fg]{title in head/foot}\beamer@shorttitle}
  {}{}
\xpatchcmd{\insertshorttitle}
  {{\beamer@shorttitle}}
  {{\usebeamercolor*[fg]{title in head/foot}\beamer@shorttitle}}
  {}{}
\makeatother
```

The second patch must be different, because we don't want to add again the code before the *first* occurrence of `\beamer@shorttitle`.

You could do with just one patch by using the experimental package `regexpatch`:

```
\usepackage{regexpatch}
\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd*{\insertshorttitle}
  {\beamer@shorttitle}
  {\usebeamercolor*[fg]{title in head/foot}\beamer@shorttitle}
  {}{}
\makeatother
```

The *-variant patches every occurrence. Note that you can't load both `xpatch` and `regexpatch`.

Comment: (+1) but, just out of curiosity, is this preferable to using `\renewcommand`? (And, if so, why?) Or is it just an alternative?

Comment: @cfr It's an alternative, sometimes easier because it avoids pasting several code lines.

Comment: Ah. Easiness is in the head of the doer, I see.