# Why does \partpage create a hyperlink to itself?

Tags: beamer, navigation

The minimal example

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document} 
\part{About the beauty of numbers} 
\frame{\partpage}
\end{document}
```

produces a hyperlink from the part title on a `\partpage`-slide whose destination is the slide itself. Is this intentional and if so, what is the purpose?

Comment: It's not limited to `\partpage`, section page etc. make the same, as they insert the section title via `\insertsection` which creates the hyperlink - which is nice if the macro is used on another page and does not hurt on the section page. Having two separate macros would be more confusing in my opinion.

Comment: If you don't like this, you can turn it off in the part page definition, by using the technique from http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/183357/36296

Comment: I understand, thank you. I think your comments are worth being compiled as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behaviour is not limited to `\partpage`, `\sectionpage` and simimal do the same.

The reason behind this is, that the title of the current section/part/etc. is inserted via a macro `\insertsection` which creates the hyperlink. On the section page, this might seem superfluous (but does not hurt, as far as I can see), but if the macro is used on any other page, the hyperlink can be handy.

To turn this off, one could redefine the section page template, using the technique described in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/183357/36296