# Disable hyperlink when hidden in beamer

Tags: beamer, links, hyperlink

In the following example, I have a hyperlink that only appears after a `\pause`, or on `\onslide`, etc. However, the clickable hyperlink region is active even when the hyperlink text itself is hidden (i.e. we can click the empty region where the hyperlink text will appear even on the very first slide). I would like the hyperlink only to be clickable when it is visible. I also do not want to have to manually annotate hyperlinks with the slide on which they should appear, e.g. explicitly writing `<2>`. Is this possible?

```latex
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{First frame}
    The hyperlink only appears...
    
    \onslide<2->{...after a pause. Then we can click \ref{def}.} This text...

    ...and this text should always be visible.
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Second frame}
    \begin{definition}
        \label{def}
        Here is a definition.
    \end{definition}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

A screenshot of the issue (the pointer is over the hyperlink region):
[image: an active invisible hyperlink]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `\pause` the content is still present on the first overlay, just not visible.

If you want something to not be present, you can use `\only`. To avoid hard coding overlay numbers, you can use relative overlays:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

%\setbeamercovered{transparent}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{First frame}
    The hyperlink only appears...\pause
    
    ...after a pause. Then we can click \only<.(1)->{\ref{def}}.
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Second frame}
    \begin{definition}
        \label{def}
        Here is a definition.
    \end{definition}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Or `\alt` if the link should still occupy space:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

%\setbeamercovered{transparent}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{First frame}
    The hyperlink only appears...
    
    \uncover<+(1)->{...after a pause. Then we can click \alt<-.>{\phantom{\ref{def}}}{\ref{def}}.} This text...

    ...and this text should always be visible.
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Second frame}
    \begin{definition}
        \label{def}
        Here is a definition.
    \end{definition}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: To be clear, I still want the hyperlinked text to take up space, which doesn't happen with `\only`. I'll update my example.

Comment: @varkor You could use `\alt` to add dummy space instead

Comment: I suppose this does the trick. Is there a way to specify an overlay relative to something like the current `\onslide`, so that this method works also for the updated example in the question?

Comment: @varkor seems to work fine with the example from your question

Comment: For your new use case `\alt<.->` should be easier.

Comment: With `\onslide<2->{...after a pause. Then we can click \alt<.->{\ref{def}}{\phantom{\ref{def}}}.}`, the hyperlink is still present (it's not with `\alt<2->`). Did I misunderstand what you meant?

Comment: @varkor see my updated answer.

Comment: Thanks for your help: the second solution works well, especially with a new command `\newcommand{\bref}[1]{\alt<-.>{\phantom{\ref{#1}}}{\ref{#1}}}` to make things more readable. I also realised my question really refers to `\visible` rather than `\uncover`, because in the latter case the hyperlinked text is still visible with `\setbeamercovered{transparent}`.

Answer (score 0):

Different approach: based on this idea by @Werner https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/183357/36296 you could temporarily disable hyperlinks:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\setbeamercovered{transparent}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\hyperoff}{\let\hyperlink\@secondoftwo}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{First frame}
    The hyperlink only appears...
    
    \uncover<+(1)->{% 
      \begingroup%
      \only<-.>{\hyperoff}%
      ...after a pause. Then we can click \ref{def}.%
      \endgroup%
    } This text...

    ...and this text should always be visible. \ref{def}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Second frame}
    \begin{definition}
        \label{def}
        Here is a definition.
    \end{definition}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```