# Beamer - How to make font larger for page numbers?

Tags: beamer, page-numbering

I've added the following code from this [answer:](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/137028/73454)

```
\addtobeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}{%
    \usebeamerfont{footline}%
    \usebeamercolor[fg]{footline}%
    \hspace{1em}%
    \insertframenumber/\inserttotalframenumber
}
```

I was wondering if there is an easy addition to make the page number font larger?

PS. I don't quite understand what that code does.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can simply put `\large` or `\huge` or whatever you like before `\insertframenumber`.

This code adds the frame number (with `\insertframenumber`) a slash, and the total frame number (with `\inserttotalframenumber`) to the already defined `navigation symbols` template. It also tells beamer to use the font defined as `footline` and the foreground (`fg`) color also defined as `footline`. This comes a horizontal space of `1em` after the existing `navigation symbols`. The following code might help clarify. Note I've changed the color to match the title, and made the font `\huge`.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\addtobeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}{%
    \usebeamerfont{footline}%
    \usebeamercolor[fg]{title}%
    \hspace{5em}%
    \huge\insertframenumber/\inserttotalframenumber
}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Frametitle}
Text
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

A simpler version than the selected answer, which produces the same result:

```
\setbeamertemplate{footline}[frame number]{}
\setbeamercolor{footline}{fg=blue}
\setbeamerfont{footline}{size=\bf\large}
```