# How can I hide the navigation symbols from specific Beamer slides?

Tags: beamer, navigation

I'm using my navigation symbols as page numbers, as in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/137028/95221). Is there a way to hide them from certain specific slides, like the title and TOC slides? The `plain` frame option doesn't work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Of course, you can use `\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}` to suppress navigation symbols. To limit its scope, we can simply put it with the frames it is supposed to affect into a local group.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\title{Awesome presentation}
\author{John Smith}
\date{A high-profile conference}

\AtBeginSection[]{%
  \begingroup
  \setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
  \begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Outline}
  \tableofcontents[currentsection]
  \end{frame}
  \endgroup
}

\begin{document}

\begingroup
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\frame[plain]{\titlepage}
\endgroup

\begingroup
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Outline}
\tableofcontents
\end{frame}
\endgroup

\section{Introduction}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Introduction}
Hi!
\end{frame}

\section{Results}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Results}
Isn't this awesome?
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Thank you!}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Here is the output (7 frames in total):

[image: frame sample]

Comment: What about hiding the navigation bar only for one overlay of one frame? Is it possible?