# Beamer slide counter

Tags: beamer, counters

Is it possible to set a section counter in beamer? For example, when using the Frankfurt theme it displays a counter in each section you are in.

This is problematic if you have multiple sections or long titles. Is it possible to just have a counter at the bottom of the slide?

Comment: See e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/137028/121799.

Comment: @marmot I used your hint as a possible duplicate.