# Latex Beamer Custom “Out of” Slide Number

Tags: beamer

I am doing Latex beamer and I want to have all slides appear out of 100 no matter how many slides I have.

So slide 1 will be: 1/100 slide 2 will be: 2/100 slide 3 will be: 3/100

I have no idea to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to TeX-SE! All I am doing here is to subject the code from [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/137028/121799) to a trivial modification, i.e. replace `\inserttotalframenumber` by `100`.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\addtobeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}{%
    \usebeamerfont{footline}%
    \usebeamercolor[fg]{footline}%
    \hspace{1em}%
    \insertframenumber/100
}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t]
\frametitle{A frame}
No honey liquor. 
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[t]
\frametitle{Another frame}
Sad.
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If this solution does not work for you because you, say, use a specific template: this is precisely the reason why many users here insist on a minimal working example (MWE). And presumably the lack of the MWE is the reason why your question didn't get too much attention.