# Allowed parameters to \addtobeamertemplate

Tags: beamer

Question: How do I get a complete list of the available arguments to `\addtobeamertemplate`?

Background: I want to modify the footline template in the Frankfurt theme.  I found some sample code at [How to insert page number in Beamer navigation symbols?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/137022/how-to-insert-page-number-in-beamer-navigation-symbols) that looks helpful:

```latex
\addtobeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}{%
   \usebeamerfont{footline}%
   \usebeamercolor[fg]{footline}%
   \hspace{1em}%
   \insertframenumber/\inserttotalframenumber
}
```

Googling `\addtobeamertemplate` I see other arguments: `frametitle`, `footline`, `title page`. In the Beamer documentation I see `frame begin` and `frame end` (p. 63), `headline` (p. 64), and `logo` (p. 74).

How do I get a complete list of the available arguments to `\addtobeamertemplate`?

Answer (score 3):

The beamer documentation's index has an entry for "Beamer template" that has a long sublist of entries.  I'm assuming that's a complete list.